# How to dynamically choose dataset according to parameter on SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

I have an SSRS report that is currently working. Now we are going to roll out to project to different sites (same schema from the database, but it will load data from a different table).
My idea was adding an expression that would be modified according to the following example:

```
=switch(Parameters!SiteTable.Value = "1", "select iReportID, sReportName, dtLastUpdated from \""::Company_Table1\"" order by iReportID desc", Parameters!SiteTable.Value = "2", "select iReportID, sReportName, dtLastUpdated from \""::Company_Table2\"" order by iReportID desc")
```

My datasource is loading from an Oracle database.
Is my idea correct? Is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use 2 `tablix` and toggle the visibility based on the parameter.

---

#### Visibility Expression

```
=IIF(Parameters!SiteTable.Value = "1", true, false)
```

#### Tablix Properites

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Using a function for the query would work but the text syntax for an expression uses & to concatenate strings. You would need to close the string with a ", use & and then the parameter. I think your expression would give an error with the escapes and Oracle Parameter indicator :: . If the parameters are in Oracle, I think you would add them without escaping out of the string (`from ::Company_Table2 order by...`) - though I'm not sure if parameters can be used for object names.

```
=switch(Parameters!SiteTable.Value = "1", 
        "select iReportID, sReportName, dtLastUpdated from " & Parameters!Company_Table1.Value & " order by iReportID desc", 
    Parameters!SiteTable.Value = "2", 
        "select iReportID, sReportName, dtLastUpdated from " & Parameters!Company_Table2.Value & " order by iReportID desc")
```